# Rhadoop - wordcount output is coming but not in a readable format

Tags: r, hadoop, rhadoop

I followed this link's wordcount program. The link is given by "[Rhadoop - wordcount using rmr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30261383/rhadoop-wordcount-using-rmr)"
Iam getting the output but it is not in readable format. I want key value pairs in my output. How do I get that. What modifications should I do to the code. Please help me with this.

here is the output

hadoop@hadoop-vm:~/apache/hadoop-1.2.1$ bin/hadoop fs -cat /user/hadoop/out10/part*
SEQ /org.apache.hadoop.typedbytes.TypedBytesWritable/org.apache.hadoop.typedbytes.TypedBytesWritablea �9D_5X ��&�\hadoop@hadoop-vm:~/apache/hadoop-1.2.1$

here is the code

```
Sys.setenv("HADOOP_CMD"="/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop")
Sys.setenv("HADOOP_STREAMING"="/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.4.0.jar")

# load librarys
library(rmr2)
library(rhdfs)

# initiate rhdfs package
hdfs.init()

map <- function(k,lines) {
  words.list <- strsplit(lines, '\\s')
  words <- unlist(words.list)
  return( keyval(words, 1) )
}

reduce <- function(word, counts) {
  keyval(word, sum(counts))
}

wordcount <- function (input, output=NULL) {
  mapreduce(input=input, output=output, input.format="text", map=map, reduce=reduce)
}

## read text files from folder example/wordcount/data
hdfs.root <- 'example/wordcount'
hdfs.data <- file.path(hdfs.root, 'data')

## save result in folder example/wordcount/out
hdfs.out <- file.path(hdfs.root, 'out')

## Submit job
out <- wordcount(hdfs.data, hdfs.out) 

## Fetch results from HDFS
results <- from.dfs(out)
results.df <- as.data.frame(results, stringsAsFactors=F)
colnames(results.df) <- c('word', 'count')

head(results.df)
```

Comment: paste your codes and your output here to clarify your question for getting better help. :)

Comment: Here is the output                                                             
hadoop@hadoop-vm:~/apache/hadoop-1.2.1$ bin/hadoop fs -cat /user/hadoop/out10/part*
SEQ /org.apache.hadoop.typedbytes.TypedBytesWritable/org.apache.hadoop.typedbytes.TypedBytesWritablea �9D_5X ��&�\hadoop@hadoop-vm:~/apache/hadoop-1.2.1$

Comment: The code for the link is given by "Rhadoop - wordcount using rmr"

Comment: you should paste the output into your question, not here.