# Having issues with RHADOOP?

Tags: r, hadoop, rstudio-server, rhadoop

I have checked the question : [Rhadoop - wordcount using rmr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30261383/rhadoop-wordcount-using-rmr)  and have tried the answer on my side. But it is giving a lot of issues.
Here is the code:

```
Sys.setenv("HADOOP_CMD"="/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop")
Sys.setenv("HADOOP_STREAMING"="/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.4.0.jar")

# load librarys
library(rmr2)
library(rhdfs)

# initiate rhdfs package
hdfs.init()

map <- function(k,lines) {
  words.list <- strsplit(lines, '\\s')
  words <- unlist(words.list)
  return( keyval(words, 1) )
}

reduce <- function(word, counts) {
  keyval(word, sum(counts))
}

wordcount <- function (input, output=NULL) {
  mapreduce(input=input, output=output, input.format="text", map=map, reduce=reduce)
}

## read text files from folder example/wordcount/data
hdfs.root <- 'example/wordcount'
hdfs.data <- file.path(hdfs.root, 'data')

## save result in folder example/wordcount/out
hdfs.out <- file.path(hdfs.root, 'out')

## Submit job
out <- wordcount(hdfs.data, hdfs.out) 

## Fetch results from HDFS
results <- from.dfs(out)
results.df <- as.data.frame(results, stringsAsFactors=F)
colnames(results.df) <- c('word', 'count')

head(results.df)
```

Here are the issues:

https://justpaste.it/143a0
I don't understand the problem and what should be the solution for this particular problem. Kindly help me and let me know what is the solution for this particular problem.
I am using the RStudio-Server and R with latest versions.

Comment: what is the hadoop version? In the code pasted above the hadoop streaming jar version is 2.4.0, however in the issue link it says 2.7.3!

Comment: Similar to your question has been answered in the following link, see if that helps!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29419318/streaming-command-failed-in-rhadoop